# Как узнать количество одинаковых элементов в двух списках?

Tags: python, list, список

У меня есть 2 списка с ответами, правильные ответы и ответы пользователя, надо сравнить два списка и узнать количество одинаковых элементов в списке, кол-во правильных ответов записать в переменную.

```
answers = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]
user_answers = [2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

например, так

**вариант 1:**

```
answers = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]
user_answers = [2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]

count = sum(i[0] == i[1] for i in zip(answers, user_answers))
```

**вариант 2:**

те же яйки, только сбоку

```
count = len([i for i in zip(answers, user_answers) if i[0] == i[1]])
```

**вариант 3:**

```
count = len(set(enumerate(answers)) & set(enumerate(user_answers)))
```

Answer (score 1):

в коллекцию вариантов:

```
import numpy as np

answers =      [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]
user_answers = [2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]

corr_answers = sum(np.array(answers)==np.array(user_answers))  # 7
```